# Can I use a 32x6mm catridge fuse with a fuse holder specified at 38x10mm

Tags: wiring, fuses, panel

This is my first time incorporating fuses in my project. I am trying to source for some DIN rail mount fuse holders and the accompanying cartridge fuses.

After much searching, I have found the fuse I am looking for with a current specification of 500mA. This fuse also has size 32mm x 6mm.

However I can't seem to find a fuse holder with the physical specifications. All I come across is fuse holders with size specifications of 38mm x 10mm.

Will it be possible to use a 32x6 fuse with a 38x10 holder?

Comment: They are [available](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/connectors/terminal-blocks-din-rail-terminals/fused-din-rail-terminals/?applied-dimensions=4294845716). Maybe you need to look harder.

Comment: @SteveG I am bit restricted to the shop to purchase from (Aliexpress). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

No. Even if the fuse seems to fit, it should not be used with a holder that is not specifically designed for the fuse. Fuse performance specifications and independent testing laboratory listings are dependent on use with a fuse holder that is designed for that fuse.

Comment: Thanks. Needed some one to talk me out of this idea. No cutting corners!!

Answer (score 0):

32 × 6 mm is the old 1.25" x 1/4" fuse style. There are plenty of DIN holders for these. Your search term is [din rail 32 x 6.35 fuse terminal](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=677&ei=-y1cXYrlBrim1fAPpNefkA8&q=din+rail+32+x+6.35+fuse+terminal&oq=din+rail+32+x+6.35+fuse+terminal5).

Comment: yeah, that's the old "3AG" size